# Add multiple folder in FTPSync ignore

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

My folder structure is

```
Project
|
+--cache
|
+--class
|
+--plugins
|
+--server
```

I can add a single folder in ignore by `\\\\cache\\\\`. But how can I add multiple folders like `class` and `server` in ignore?

Comment: I don't use that plugin, but it looks like the `ignore` setting is a regex, so you may want to try separating each entry with a pipe character, e.g. `\\\\cache\\\\|\\\\class\\\\`.

Comment: @OdatNurd That works fine. By the way are there any better plugins than FTPSync???

Comment: I use SFTP, but it's a paid plugin. https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SFTP